# Printing a matrix and numbers under the second diagonal

Tags: c, matrix, printing

My task is to print out a matrix of integer numbers scanned from the keyboard, and then to print out the numbers under the second diagonal using separate functions. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//array[n][n] = 2D array of n rows and n columns
//n = number of rows and columns
void printmatrix(int n, int array[n][n]){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

void undersdiagonal(int n, int array[n][n]){
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        /**/
        for(int j = 1; (j < n); j++){
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return;
} 

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int integermatrix[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &integermatrix[i][j]);
        }    
    }
    printf("The entered matrix is:\n");
    //calls first function to print matrix 
    printmatrix(n, integermatrix);
    printf("Under the secondary diagonal:\n");
    //calls second function to print numbers under main diagonal 
    undersdiagonal(n,integermatrix);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out how to print out the numbers under the second main diagonal from the function

```
void undersdiagonal(int n, int array[n][n]).
```

My input looks like this:

```
3
1
2
3
4 
5
6
7
8
9
```

And the output looks like this:

```
The entered matrix is:
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
Under the secondary diagonal:
5 6 8 9
```

But I want the output to be:

```
The entered matrix is:
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
Under the secondary diagonal:
6 8 9
```

What could I change in the 'for' loop within the 'for' loop in the function

```
void undersdiagonal(int n, int array[n][n])
```

?

Comment: Wouldn't the secondary diagonal be `3 5 7` and under the secondary diagonal be `6 8 9`?

Comment: yes, but my code prints 5 as well

Answer (score 1):

The key is with the inner loop of `undersdiagonal`:

As currently written, `for(int j = 1; (j < n); j++){` starts with the second column (column `1`) every single time.  It needs to start on a different column for each row.

- For a **3×3** matrix, the second row (row `1`) will begin on the last column (column **`2`**).  For a **4×4** matrix, the second row (row `1`) will begin on the last column (column **`3`**)... So there is a *direct* relationship between the starting column (`j`) and the matrix size: `n`.
- Every time the row number goes **up** one, the starting column goes **down** one.  So there is an *inverse* relationship between the starting column (`j`) and the row: `- i`.

Take those two pieces together and you have `int j = n - i;`